# Use lambdas of java8 as a method parameter to avoid redundancy

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a class with a lot of methods like this **(very simplified)**:

```
public Record[] getRecordForXXX(String username, String param1) throws MyException {
    User user = getUser(String username); // Always the same
    MyObject myObj = getMyObject(param1); // Always the same

    // Here is the only line of code, this is different in any of thoose methods
    Record[] recs = getRecords1(user, myObject); // or getRecords2(user, myObject) ...

    // Handle those records always the same ...
    handleRecords(recs); // Always the same
    return recs; // Always the same
}
```

Is there any way to use lambdas to avoid the redundancy like:

```
   public Record[] getRecord(String userName, String param1, XXX method) throws MyException {
        User user = getUser(String username); // Always the same
        MyObject myObj = getMyObject(param1); // Always the same

        // => Call the given 'method' using the parameters user and myObj and returning records

        // Handle those records always the same ...
        handleRecords(recs); // Always the same
        return recs;  // Always the same
   }
```

I know, I can use some kind of interface (command-pattern) to do this, but I like to use a more functionality approach ... TIA!

Comment: Look into [`BiFunction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html).  The method parameter would be `BiFunction<User,MyObject,Record[]>`.  Is that sufficient?

Comment: @ajb Unfortunatly, it is not sufficient: I need `QuadFunction<User, MyObject, SecObj, ThirdObj, Record[]>)`. But it should not be so hard to implement such an interface analogous to `BiFunction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
public Record[] getRecord(String userName, String param1, BiFunction<User, MyObject, Record[]> method) throws MyException {
    User user = getUser(String username); // Always the same
    MyObject myObj = getMyObject(param1); // Always the same

    Record[] recs = method.apply(user, myObj);

    // Handle those records always the same ...
    handleRecords(recs); // Always the same
    return recs;  // Always the same
}
```

You can call your new function as follows:

```
yourObject.getRecord(userName, param1, (aUserName, aParam1) -> {
    // do some stuff with aUserName and aParam1
    return aRecordArray;
})
```

Comment: It seems to be my example was to much simplified. In fact, I have more than two parameters. Do I need to implement my own `FunctionalInterface` therefore?

Comment: It would probably be best to write your own functional interface. Assuming the number and types of parameters are constant, it should be straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

```
public Record[] getRecordForXXX(String username, String param1, BiFunction<User, MyObject, Record[]> loader) throws MyException {
    User user = getUser(String username); // Always the same
    MyObject myObj = getMyObject(param1); // Always the same

    Record[] recs = loader.apply(user, myObject);

    // Handle those records always the same ...
    handleRecords(recs); // Always the same
    return recs; // Always the same
}

getRecordForXXX("user", "param1", ClassName::getRecords1);
getRecordForXXX("user", "param1", ClassName::getRecords2);
```

Comment: The methods `getRecords1()` and `getRecords2()` must they be static?

Comment: @t777: You can also use `this::getRecords1` and `this::getRecords2` for non-static methods.

Comment: @t777 If you have a `getRecords1` method of `User` that takes one `MyObject` argument and returns `Records[]`, you can use `User::getRecords1`.  Also, you don't have to use a method reference (the `::` syntax); you can use a lambda as the third parameter to `getRecordForXXX`.

Answer (score 2):

Although lambdas may be effective here you won't be using them for what they are really for. You are looking for the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and enums can make an excellent implementation of a strategy pattern.

```
enum Type {

    XXX {

                @Override
                Record[] forType(User user, MyObject obj) {
                    // Something here.
                    return null;
                }
            },
    YYY {

                @Override
                Record[] forType(User user, MyObject obj) {
                    // Something here.
                    return null;
                }
            };

    abstract Record[] forType(User user, MyObject obj);
}

public Record[] getRecord(String userName, String param1, Type type) throws MyException {
    User user = getUser(userName); // Always the same
    MyObject myObj = getMyObject(param1); // Always the same

    // Use the Type to choose the strategy to grow the records.
    Recs recs = type.forType(user, myObj);

    // Handle those records always the same ...
    handleRecords(recs); // Always the same
    return recs;  // Always the same
}
```

Comment: A really nice idea! I have to evaluate, if that works in a (spring) transactional context.

Comment: Why do you think: "you won't be using them [lambdas] for what they are really for"?

Comment: @t777 - *why do you think ...* - Because lambdas are several steps beyond simple strategies - they provide not just a functional interface but type safety and local parameter encapsulation along with all sorts of other benefits. IMHO they are a sledgehammer to crack a nut in this case. When you have a strategy problem you should use a strategy solution.

Comment: Strategy is proven pattern and there's no need for the new shiny thing. You can of course implement that same way on lambdas, as you need some general interface specified, but there's no need. +1 for this solution from me